# Calling initializer_list constructor via make_unique/make_shared

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, c++14, initializer-list

I'm trying to use `std::make_unique` to instanciate a class whose constructor is to receive an `std::initializer_list`. Here a minimal case :

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
    Foo(std::initializer_list<std::string> strings) : strings(strings) {}

    std::vector<std::string> strings;
};

int main(int, char**) {

    auto ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>({"Hello", "World"});

    return 0;
}
```

You can see on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad872ef17595764c) that it doesn't build :

```
main.cpp:14:56: error: no matching function for call to 'make_unique(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
     auto ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>({"Hello", "World"});
```

So, is `make_unique` reportedly unable to use `initializer_list`s ? Is there a bug in GCC 4.9.1 ? Or did I overlook something ?

Comment: Braced lists cannot be deduced by template argument deduction. Try `make_unique<Foo>(std::initializer_list<std::string>({"Hello", "World"}))`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, that looks like an answer to me :)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes it does ! But ugh, that syntax. `initializer_list`s are definitely strange gizmos. In that particular case I think I'll just construct the `unique_ptr` from a `new` call.

Comment: That's a shame, but understandable. `std::initializer_list` is a terrible misdesign. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hey, try this: `std::make_unique<Foo, std::initializer_list<std::string>>({"Hello", "World"})`

Comment: @Quentin how about: `auto il { "Hello"s, "World"s }; auto ptr = make_unique<Foo>(il);` ?

Comment: @PiotrS.: Good call, mind if I steal that?

Comment: @KerrekSB that's fine. but I can't recall the proper rule that will be introduced, whether `auto` will require `=` to deduce `initializer_list<T>` or not

Comment: @KerrekSB and it requires `using std::operator "" s;`, as it seems that OP qualifies all names with `std::`

Comment: @PiotrS.: I'm not sure if this has changed, I thought this has always been well-defined in C++11? Maybe not, I don't have a non-head standard ready.

Comment: @PiotrS.: Thanks - I was just wondering why I didn't have that literal. Shame, why isn't that in the global namespace.

Comment: I'm looking at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3588.txt - Q1. Not sure if related since I'm not really getting that part..

Comment: @KerrekSB [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) proposes to add a change that will require `=` to use `initializer_list` in `auto`

Comment: @MarcoA.: Deduction from `auto` is in  [dcl.spec.auto]
.

Comment: @PiotrS.: Interesting. I don't think it has been voted in yet, definitely not into C++14. It may well make it into C++17, though.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`std::make_unique` is a function template which deduces the argument types which are passed to the object constructor. Unfortunately, braced lists are not deducible (with an exception for `auto` declarations), and so you cannot instantiate the function template when that missing parameter type.

You can either not use `std::make_unique`, but please don't go that route – you should avoid naked `new`s as much as you can, for the children's sake. Or you can make the type deduction work by specifying the type:

- `std::make_unique<Foo>(std::initializer_list<std::string>({"Hello", "World"}))`
- `std::make_unique<Foo, std::initializer_list<std::string>>({"Hello", "World"})`
- `auto il = { "Hello"s, "World"s }; auto ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>(il);`

The last option uses the special rule for `auto` declarations, which (as I hinted above) *do* in fact deduce an `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: You say `std::initializer_list<std::string>({"Hello", "World"})`, why not `std::initializer_list<std::string>{"Hello", "World"}`?

Answer (score 10):

If you're prepared to type a few extra characters, you can do this:

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>( make_init_list( { "Hello"s , "World"s } ));
```

where `init_list` is defined as

```
template<typename T>
std:: initializer_list<T> make_init_list ( std:: initializer_list<T> && l ) {
    return l;
}
```

This allows the deduction to occur, and is convenient if there are many places in the code you must do this.

(Works on clang 3.9 and gcc 6.2.0. I got it to work on g++-4.8.4 also, except I had to tweak the `std::string`-literal and change to `make_shared`. But the deduction of `T` within `make_init_list` worked fine.)

Actually, it this an extension? Is successful deduction for `make_init_list` required by the standard or not?