# Initializing a unique_ptr to an array with an initializer_list

Tags: c++

```
std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, 3>> nums = std::make_unique<std::array<int, 3>, std::initializer_list<int>>({ 5, 6, 7 });
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379311/calling-initializer-list-constructor-via-make-unique-make-shared) that this is the way to do it, but the compiler throws the following error:
[C2664](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2664?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2664)%26rd%3Dtrue): 'std::array::array(std::array &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::initializer_list' to 'const std::array &'

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: In the other example `Foo` has a constructor taking an `initializer_list` parameter. `std::array` does not have that.

Comment: @BoPersson that sounds like an answer

Comment: @BoPersson Ah I see, is there another way to quickly initialize a `unique_ptr<array>`?

Comment: what about `std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, 3>> nums = std::make_unique<std::array<int, 3>>(std::array<int, 3>{ 1, 2, 3 });` quick enough?

Comment: In common practice, STL containers with unique_ptr help to avoid costly operations, or when an object can't be copied, like std::thread. Is there any strict need to use point wrappers around STL containers?

Comment: @SmitYcyken I want to return the array from a function.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Doesn't this copy the array?

Comment: @FirstProphet Looks to me like a case for compiler copy elision

Comment: If you want to modify the existing array why not to use `void do_smth(std::vector<std::string>& result);`. It seems to be bad practice to return a vector from a function.

Comment: @SmitYcyken I thought about that, but it's sort of annoying to have to manually create a new array everytime I want to call the function. I was hoping there is an easy way for a function to create and return an array...

Comment: If you really want to return an array of 3 int's, it will be much faster to pass it by value instead of allocating it on the heap. Then it might even get optimized away with 0 memory access.

Comment: @rustyx It's more about the general concept of things, imagine it were an array of 1 billion ints or whatever ...

Comment: @FirstProphet, how about using iterators? Instead of a returning a collection you take an output iterator as argument. It's more flexible too.